# Discord JS: ¡Reaction Collector!

Tags: javascript

mi duda es si puedo obtener la id del usuario sin estar en la función de mensaje ejemplo la guía me da esto:

```
client.on('message', message => {
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);

});

})
```

Teniendo claro esto quiero ponerlo en una función ready:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
})
```

el problema es que puedo declarar la funcion message pero el problema reside en que el usuario que manda el mensaje es el bot pero cuando un usuario reacciona al mensaje coge el author del mensaje que es el bot pero quiero la información del usuario que ha reaccionado no del author del mensaje que en este caso es el bot mi pregunta es:

**¿Como puedo obtener la id de la persona que ha reaccionado y no la del author del mensaje ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilices el evento de [messageReactionAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd)

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  // If the message this reaction belongs to was removed the fetching might result in an API error, which we need to handle
    try {
      await reaction.fetchUsers();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`${reaction.message.author.username}'s message "${reaction.message.content.toString()}" gained a reaction!`);
    console.log(`${user.username} reacted with "${reaction.emoji.name}".`);
    console.log(`${reaction.count} user(s) have given the same reaction to this message!`);
});
```

Espero que esto te sirva!